# too late to be an Ethereum smart contract developer with Eth2.0 coming?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

He’ll y’all,

I’m interested in learning about ethereum smart contract development however I’m worried my time spent learning will go to waste with eth2.0 coming.

Will I be wasting my time learning smart context development with eth1.0???

Any help clarifying would be greatly appreciated.

Also any good learning material suggestions would be awesome!

Thank you

Comment: In the future, I suggest to attract more high quality answers to your question, you spell it with professional English.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum 2.0 does not even have roadmap for yet when it is going to enable smart contracts, or ever. It is still perfectly fine to start learning Solidity, the smart contract programming language. Solidity is not used only on Ethereum 1.0, but on multiple smart contract virtual machines.